# How do I enforce starting order over different services defined inside a yaml file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, dockerfile

I have a `local.yml` file in which I have defined 3 services: `service3` depends on `service2`, `service2` depends on `service1`. I want to enforce a starting order between them: `service1` starts firs, then `service2`, then `service3`. What is very important for me is that `service3` is the last one to start.

What I tried to do is adding the following piece of code inside `service3`:

```
services:
  service3:
    healthcheck:
      test: curl http://localhost:8080/someUrl || exit 1
      interval: 10s
    build:
      context: ./myDir
      dockerfile: ./dockerfile3
    depends_on:
      - service2

  service2:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: /dockerfile2
    depends_on:
      - service1   

  service1:
    image: service1_image
```

However  `http://localhost:8080/someUrl` is available before `serivce2` finishes its starting. What I see right now in the logs (as starting order) is the following:

```
service1      |.......
service1      |.......
service2      |.......
service2      |.......
service3      |....... //starts after the url is available
service3      |....... //prints that service3 is available
service2      |....... //and then service2 continues to build
service2      |.......
service2      |.......
```

How do I display the log messages from `service3` at the end? I.e. how do I start service3 in the last order?

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y)